# Failing to deploy Elixir application on Heroku because of dependency on a private repo

Tags: heroku, elixir, semaphore-ci

I'm using heroku's [buildpack for Elixir](https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir) and one of the dependencies is failing with `mix deps.get` because it's from a private Github repository.

When I tried deploying I got this error:

```
remote: * Getting my_library (https://github.com/my_organization/my_library.git)
remote: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
remote: ** (Mix) Command "git --git-dir=.git fetch --force --quiet --progress" failed
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Elixir app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

I tried adding `GITHUB_API_TOKEN` in Heroku's config vars but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Elixir webpack does not include the steps for handling private GitHub dependencies. You can include this buildpack though to setup GitHub accordingly: https://github.com/timshadel/heroku-buildpack-github-netrc